# Executing an executable file by double clicking without terminal showing up

Tags: c++, macos, terminal, g++, executable

I want to automate some simple tasks using c++. For example I want a specific text file to be created automatically when executing the *automate* executable. However, when I double click on that file, the terminal pops up. Is there an option I can add to my compiler or a method to my *automate.cpp* file such that the terminal runs headless? This is my .cpp file.

```
 #include <filesystem>
 #include <fstream>
 
 int main() {

     std::ofstream outfile("test.txt");
     outfile << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
     outfile.close();

     std::system("mv test.txt ~/Desktop");

 }
```

Comment: Unrelated: Don't use `std::system` to move files. Use [`std::filesystem::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/rename) or, prior to C++17, [`std::rename`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/rename).

Comment: You can't really do anything within the executable itself, because what's happening is that Launch Services is treating your program as a *document* that happens to be openable in the Terminal application. To avoid this, I think you either need to make another app that you can associate this "document" with (that'll execute it headless), or actually convert the executable into something LS will treat as an app, with something like [appify](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/674099) or [Platypus](https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus).

Comment: Thank's a lot! Of course I've tried to find the answer on google, gut it seems like I did not exactly now how to express my question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a console window to appear, then don't create a console app to begin with.  Create a GUI app instead, and just omit creating any UI windows.